# Genymotion unstable

Tags: android-studio, genymotion

I've been using Genymotion, but its been pretty laggy. I only had HAXM accelerator installed so I decided to mess with VM manager, but it only seems to have made it worse. Now it runs smoothly but upon opening any application, it will either wait a bit then tell me the application isn't responding, or just freeze all together and give me a "player.exe has stopped working" dialog box. My changed system settings are as follows:

1 processor,
1024MB for the motherboard,
128MB for video with 3D acceleration enabled.
All other configurations are set to default.

I have an intel i5-2450M 2.5GHz chip with virtualization enabled in the BIOS.

Before when I had only HAXM installed, it worked fine. Just lagged a lot.

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Windows 10?
Try to reinstall genymotion deleting all geny folders from your computer, remove virtualbox too.